# Command line dvd creation with chapters and menu

Tags: command-line, video, dvd, batch

I have several personal video and I would like to put them on a dvd. 
I would like to classify them by year; so the menu would list the year, and each video should be a chapter.
I could do that with a gui program like Devede, 2mandvd,... but as I have a lots of videos, and as I just want to organise them by date, it could be faster to automate the creation with a script.
So, is there a tool which can create menus and chapter and that I can integrate in a batch  script?

Answer (score 1):

Probably [dvdauthor](http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/) could be used for your task, although it might take some work to get the results you desire. You'd have to use your script to write an XML input file for dvdauthor.

I'd start with a GUI frontend of dvdauthor to create an example input file, which then could be used as a template for the script.

Comment: probably what I need, I'm going to test it. Thank you.